# Pass Strings from iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, watchos-2

I'm trying to **pass the `color` for each `Play`** found in my CloudKit database.

*iPhone --> Watch*

iOS `TableViewController`:

```
func getCloudKit() {
    ///...
    let publicData = container.publicCloudDatabase
    publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
        if error == nil { // There is no error
            for play in results! {
                let newPlay = Play()
                do {
                    try WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.updateApplicationContext(["color" : newPlay.teamColor])
                    NSLog("NewPColor: %@", newPlay.teamColor)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                self.objects.append(newPlay)
            }
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

When I `NSLog` what is getting passed in the iOS side, it **logs the 3 `color`s** perfectly.

```
2015-09-25 21:10:28.706 Play[16444] NewPColor: FDB927
2015-09-25 21:10:28.707 Play[16444] NewPColor: 000000
2015-09-25 21:10:28.708 Play[16444] NewPColor: 000000
```

But when I go to the Watch side, **nothing shows up in the `colorLabel`**.  (I'm not sure if `setText` is even getting called there because "From iPhone" doesn't even show up.)

WatchKit `InterfaceController`:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let colorWatch = applicationContext["color"] as? String

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if let colorWatch = colorWatch {
            self.colorLabel.setText("From iPhone: \(colorWatch)")
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?  Can post any extra code as needed, just let me know.  Thanks!

**EDIT:** Per question here is my `WCSession` code

iOS `WatchSessionManager`

```
class WatchSessionManager: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate {

    static let sharedManager = WatchSessionManager()
    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    private let session: WCSession? = WCSession.isSupported() ? WCSession.defaultSession() : nil

    private var validSession: WCSession? {

        if let session = session where session.paired && session.watchAppInstalled {
            return session
        }
        return nil
    }

    func startSession() {
        session?.delegate = self
        session?.activateSession()
    }
}

extension WatchSessionManager {

    // Sender
    func updateApplicationContext(applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) throws {
        if let session = validSession {
            do {
                try session.updateApplicationContext(applicationContext)
            } catch let error {
                throw error
            }
        }
    }

    // Receiver
    func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) {
        // handle receiving application context

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // make sure to put on the main queue to update UI!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N.B. You pass 'newPlay' in the appContext dictionary, yet print 'newPlayoff' in your log.

I presume elsewhere you have set the WCSession delegate and called activateSession

Comment: Sorry that first part was a copy and paste mixup.  And for the `WCSession` code I do have that, I posted it just in case you wanted to take a peek at it.  Any ideas?  Thanks!